# .Net equivalent of JCEKS keystore

Tags: c#, encryption, keystore, keytool

I have an AES key that I generated using keytool:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias authenticationkey -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -keystore aes.jks -storepass foo -keypass bar -storetype JCEKS
```

Ignoring the problems with what I am doing, I want to use the same key in a C# program. I can extract the key from Java, and use it in C#.

I don't think I can load a JCEKS keystore in C# and keytool will not let me create an AES key in a PKCS12 store.

What is the correct keystore format for AES keys in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is out of date, but if anybody crosses by, I managed to read a JCEKS keystore in .NET successfully with the Chilkat library (also available for .NET Core).

https://www.example-code.com/csharp/jceks_read_secret_keys.asp

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this is a commercial library